# Doorbell dings, dongs, but doesn't ding-dong

Tags: transformer, doorbell

I'm replacing a doorbell chime unit.  The old one worked, but the new one does not.  If I connect the wire to the terminal labeled "front", it will ding.  If I connect the wire to the terminal labeled "rear", it dongs.  The latter makes sense as that should be so a rear or side doorbell has a different sound.  But why doesn't it ding-dong when connected to "front"?  The hammer moves freely up and down (no wire in the way blocking it).

The transformer measures only 11 volts.  That seems low, should I replace it?  If not, what else could be the problem?

Old:

[image]

New:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you haven't reversed the two red wires?

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg, I just tried swapping the red wires - same result.

Comment: I'm trying not to suggest that your dinger may be donged... To hit both notes, the electromagnet has to shoot the plunger against the spring tension fast/far enough to hit one chime, then let the spring shoot it back across fast/far enough to hit the other. Week electromagnet, weak spring, dust creating friction in the system are all possible causes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was the transformer.  I replaced it and the doorbell now works as expected.  Upon closer inspection the old transformer was only a 10V model where I needed a 16V one.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer. A few more details could really help a future visitor.